# What is the function of CCM1 and CCM2 in this resistive bridge measurement circuit?

Tags: capacitor, adc, filter

The circuit below can be found on page 59 of the ADS122C04 chip [datasheet](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/ads122c04.pdf?ts=1638364197104&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.google.com%252F#:%7E:text=The%20ADS122C04%20is%20a%20precision,applications%20measuring%20small%20sensor%20signals.&text=At%2020%20SPS%2C%20the%20digital,rejection%20for%20noisy%20industrial%20applications.). The purpose is to take the differential input of two voltages from a resistive bridge. For example, I am using it to collect data from a load cell. I understand the point of C<sub>DIF1</sub>, which is to mirror noise from one signal to the other so that the differential input is not affected by said noise. I also understand the point of R<sub>F1</sub> and R<sub>F2</sub>, which would be to allow the capacitor to do its job just as any RC circuit functions.

What I don't understand is what the point of C<sub>CM1</sub> and C<sub>CM2</sub> are. I would have thought they were there to filter out noise, but isn't that what C<sub>DIF1</sub> is for? Are they redundancy layers for each other, any noise that isn't filtered to ground gets mirrored to the other signal, and vice versa?

[image: Reference circuit from the ADS122C04 datasheet]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's two components of noise at play, both of which are worth trying to mitigate:

- one is the noise in the differential measurement across the bridge
- the other is the noise seen symmetrically on both sides of the bridge

The chip is intended to perform a differential measurement, and represent the difference between the two inputs as its output, so at first glance it seems that the common-mode noise should be ignored. However, this common-mode rejection is not perfect, and is characterized a specification known as "common-mode rejection ratio" (CMRR). At quick glance, I wasn't able to find a CMRR-vs-frequency plot in the datasheet(^), but often, CMRR gets worse with increasing frequency.

The names of the capacitors provide a key clue as well: C_DIF (for differential) vs C_CM (for Common Mode). The two CM capacitors are placed symmetrically on the two lines to ground, thus symmetrically attenuating common-mode components of any high-frequency noise.

Meanwhile, C_dif will not attenuate the common-mode component to any appreciable extent; since the common-mode noise is seen equally on both terminals, no high-frequency current flows through C_dif in response.

As the datasheet points out, the two capacitors (and likewise the two upstream series resistors) ought to be well-matched, as their mismatch will convert common-mode noise into differential noise (which then gets measured directly by the chip if not well-attenuated by C_dif).

> I understand the point of CDIF1, which is to mirror noise from one signal to the other

Not quite. It doesn't "mirror" noise from one to the other (in the sense of turning DM noise into CM noise), but rather it shunts that noise away by allowing current to pass at high frequencies in response to differential voltages, which creates a low-pass filter structure

^ CMRR is given in plots on page 14 and the table on page 8. The provided spec seems to only discuss CMRR at DC and for 50/60 Hz (likely expected powerline noise).
^^ A mechanical analogy for CMRR, for readers that prefer an intuitive visualization: Imagine measuring an object with a ruler while on a bumpy train ride; while all of the motion is common-mode (both ends of the object move together), you'll still have a difficult time with yourself, your workpiece, and the floor thrashing about.

Comment: I appreciate the insight here, and thank you for your clarification on the C_DIF cap function. But it still doesn't explain to me why/if the C-CMs are necessary. You wrote "since the common-mode noise is seen equally on both terminals" - since I'm taking a differential measurement, why do I care if there is noise on the terminals if it's identical across both? I mean I could understand if it's best practice to limit noise, but functionally my ADC output would end up being unaffected, correct?

Comment: @InBedded16 if you were taking a differential measurement with an *ideal* ADC, you would be unaffected. Your ADC is not ideal, and its ability to reject common mode noise is imperfect - common mode excitations will leak through to the output. That's what the CMRR (which I discussed in the second paragraph) characterizes.

Comment: ah okay I see. Missed that nuance the first time. Thank you.